# Calculus, limits: Can someone explain to me why $-\frac{\sqrt{2+x^2}}{2x}$ is equal to $-\frac{1}{2}$ when $x$ approaches $\infty$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals, infinity

I'm reviewing for my midterm in 3 hours and just came across this practice question/solution and don't understand it. Thank you!

[image: Limits Question]

Comment: $\displaystyle{\sqrt{2+x^2}\over 2x}=   {{\sqrt {{2\over x^2}+1}     \over 2} }$ for $x>0$.

Comment: Regarding the phrasing: this is not "equal to $-1/2$". The *limit* is equal to $-1/2$, i.e. the function gets closer and closer to $-1/2$, and stays closer and closer (not necessarily equal, though).

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering my question so quickly! I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}-\dfrac{\sqrt{2+x^2}}{2x} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}-\dfrac{\sqrt{2+x^2}/x}{2x/x} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}-\dfrac{\sqrt{2+x^2}/\sqrt{x^2}}{2} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}-\dfrac{\sqrt{2/x^2+1}}{2}$$
$$= -\dfrac{\sqrt{0+1}}{2} = -\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand now..!